# How to write a target in GNUmake to only create *.o files

Tags: gnu-make

Is there a way to write a target to

1) only create object files?

2) only to link object files and create the binary file?

I would like to be able create my binary file in 2 steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [implicit rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) for that.  Let's say you have the following Makefile:

```
CC=cc -g

all: client

client: client.c
    $(CC) client.c -o client

clean:
    -rm -f client
```

If you only want the object file, then you just need to run:

```
$ make client.o
```

And you will get the object file.  However, you can also write an explicit rule, such as:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $<
```

The previous rule is a rule to build from any `.c` file to an object (`.o`) file. `$<` helps to get the name of file where the rule depends on.

If you have several objects files, you might want to define variables then:

```
objects = client.o foo.o bar.o

client: $(objects)
    $(cc) -o $@ $(objects)

$(objects): config.h

clean:
    -rm -f client $(objects)
```

In this case, `objects` is a variable associated with the object files you want to compile.  Which is used in the rule `client` as a dependency and as argument to link them, it is also used to define rules that depends on header files (`config.h` in this example), and finalle is used in the `clean` rule to delete them to start all over again.

`$@` is a replacement for the name of the rule.  In the last case it would be `client`.

The [manual of GNU Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rules) contains a lot of examples that should enlighten your learn process.

Comment: This is what I have for "link only part". Needless to say, it is not working. Do you happen to know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It is hard to say without the error message and without the Makefile you are working on.